# "Writing" to Magento?

Tags: magento2

I am running the security scan tool on my shop and it shows my domain as being used by a botnet. I did checks and think this is a false alarm. The security scan says I should write to them to have my domain removed from the list of suspects ... the question is, **how** do I write them? There is no mail given or any other hint on how to do that.

I searched the net and found that people are indeed writing to Magento, but it never says how :-D.

Any ideas? Maybe I am not seeing the wood for the trees!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I didn't try this yet, but if you check https://magento.com/security, you will see on the left-hand side of the page an option ***'Report security issue'***, click that and it will open hackerone where you can submit your report.</strike>

Good luck!

---

***LE:*** As mentioned in the comments section, you actually don't need to report a security issue, so please check https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058131972 there is an email address there for reporting false positives. At time of writing, it is `securityscan@magento.com`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is not the correct place to write to them. I dont want to report any issue, I just want my domain removed from their list of suspects.

Comment: hmm ok, I must have misunderstood the initial problem, sorry. I updated my post with the proper answer :)